# Call function in controller using service symfony 5

Tags: symfony

I tried to call a function in a controller using service:

```
#BookManager.php
<?php

 namespace App\Service;

 use App\Entity\BookContent;
 use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;


 class BookManager
 {
protected $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

public function getBookTitle(string $page){ 
  return $this->entityManager->getRepository(BookContent::class) 
  >findOneBy(["page"=>$page])->getTitle();
 }
```

In service.yml

```
....

services:
    book.manager:
    class: App\Service\BookManager
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
    public: true
```

Finally I call it in Controller ;

```
$pageName = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest()->get('_route');
    $bookTitle = $this->container->get('book.manager')->getBookTitle($pageName);
```

But I get this error

```
Service "book.manager" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\HomeController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**

it's work when I use dependency injection but only when I do query with $id

```
$this->entityManager->getRepository(BookContent::class)- 
>findOneById(["id"=>$id])->getTitle();
```

when I do it with `findOneBy(["page"=>$page])` I get this error:

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a null variable.
```

Comment: have you tried using dependency injection? i.e. make the BookManager a parameter to either the controller's constructor or the controller's function.

Comment: @Jakumi No you have code to show me how or help to fix error...

Comment: Just for info, the container injected into AbstractController is not the master container but rather a sort of a mini-container (normally called [service locator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html)) which only holds a few services.  The source code has the details.  This explains why your posted code does not work.  In general your code should no longer use $this->container->get.  Instead you should be injecting dependencies as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Symfony 5 will autowire/auto configure your services. You can remove the `book.manager` from your *service.yaml*.

You can then use dependency injection in your controllers to access your services, like this for example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

use App\Service\BookManager; //<-- Add use

class YourController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
    * @Route("/", name="home")
    */
    public function index(Request $request, BookManager $bookManager): Response
    {
        $pageName = $request->attributes->get('_route');
        $bookTitle = $bookManager->getBookTitle($pageName);

        return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I got a new error please see EDIT above...

Comment: What is `$page`? It is not found in your database and is returning null. From your example it is the route, so in my example it is returning *home*.

Comment: no I dot var_dump and it is returning the page name correctly!!

Comment: Does it exist in the database and is there only one result? Maybe there are multiple results. Try with `findBy` instead of `findOneBy`, see what it returns..

Comment: Now is Ok,  I hade another parameter with the same name `Title`..